# Is there a Static Constrctors/Destructors Help topic

Tags: delphi, syntax, static, constructor, delphi-2010

I know in D2010 they have added support for static constructors and destructors.
Where I can find more information about they: syntax and samples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are described in the Wiki: [Class Constructors](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods#Class_Constructors) and [Class Destructors](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods#Class_Destructors).

Here is a [blog post showing their usage](http://alex.ciobanu.org/?p=258).

Answer (score 2):

Allen Bauer wrote a few blog posts about them and how they work:

http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2009/09/04/38899

http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2009/09/03/38898

http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2009/05/29/38888